# Access a keylist pair to lookup a key and return the value

Tags: c#, sql, list, parameters

```
  List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> descr = proplist();
```

How do I after getting this list, access it and lookup values from it. For example later the int of the list will equal data.propval and the string part of list will be used as cmd parameter.

```
            {
                using (DB2Connection conn = new DB2Connection())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) 

                        foreach (CollyUp data in DataUps)
                        {
                            if (data.PropVal== **int from list**)
                            {

                                DB2Command cmdtx = new DB2Command();

                                string insert = @"blah...."

                                cmdtx.Parameters.Add("@MemberNbr", data.nvr);
                                cmdtx.Parameters.Add("@LoanNbr", data.Ln);
                                cmdtx.Parameters.Add("@PropVal", data.PropValue);
                                cmdtx.Parameters.Add("@ValueDescrip", **string.Value from list**);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think you'd use a `Dictionary<int, string>` rather than `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`. Then you could use the `.Item` property or the `.TryGetValue` method to do your lookups.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Dictionary<int, string>` with its `Add()`, `Remove()` methods to add/remove items, `ContainsKey(int_key)` to check it holds *int key* and `dictionary[int_key]` to get its *string value*:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictProps = new Dictionary<int, string>();
...
dictProps.ContainsKey(int_key)
...
string val = dictProps[int_key];
```

Comment: Get an invalid argument when I write if(descr.containskey (data.propval)  .....do this

Comment: And yes I took your suggest and changed to a dictionary.

Comment: What value `data.propval` had at that time ? It must be integer for this dictionary.

Comment: Yes data.propval is an int type

Comment: Data.propval is an integer from another list

Comment: When you get invalid argument.. at complie time or runtime ?